# Mathematica NIntegrate function in C++

Tags: c++, integral-equations, mathematica

I am working on computing a challenging integral. I am working with someone else who wrote some code in Mathematica to compute it. I do not have mathematica so I am trying to do the same thing in C++. The problem is, he uses Mathematica's [NIntegrate function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) which I cannot figure out how to re-write.

How can I re-write this function in C++(or any other language)?

**Thanks.** *If you vote down, please tell me why so I can improve this question.*

Comment: We could be of greater assistance if state what exactly you want to integrate.  "A challenging integral" might mean singularities, or a family with multiple parameters, or one where no closed form is available.

Comment: @hardmath I only need to get the integral of one equation. The only thing would change would be the $x_\max$

Comment: I'm suggesting you spell out that I ntegral in order to get more specific advice on how best to write numerical integration routines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is impossible to completely rewrite `NIntegrate` because usually, it evaluates (parts of) the integrand symbolically to check for certain properties. This means, you probably have to re-implement *Mathematica* completely.

Nevertheless, if you are tackling one specific integral, I assume chances are very good that you can get similar numerical results by re-implementing some parts in C++ or using a library.

I would start by analysing (in *Mathematica*) what algorithm is used for your integral. [In this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#9009) you can find details about how *Mathematica* chooses the algorithm when `NIntegrate` uses `Method->Automatic`.

After this, you should [study the help-page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) of `NIntegrate` carefully to understand how it works. Then you should go on by

- fixing the `Method` option of `NIntegrate`
- using `EvaluationMonitor` to see where your integrand is sampled
- using specific `MaxPoints`, `MaxRecursion`, etc settings

until you finally get equally good results. If you have achieved this, then you know what algorithm you have to implement or find in C++ library.

---

Let me say that there is another way: Understand the integral you want to solve! You as human should *see* what type of integrand you have and you can check the literature, how those types are solved numerically. This is probably faster than trying to understand what *Mathematica* does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You said, " it is impossible to completely rewrite `NIntegrate`..." How is it impossible? If it is 'impossible', then how does Mathematica compute it? According to [this page][http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica], Mathematica is written in Wolfram Language, C/C++, Java and Mathematica. Since Mathematica is written in the languages, it can't be impossible to re-write the NIntegrate function. +1 for your answer and I'll keep looking for an implemantation in another language. Thanks again!

Comment: Let me try to explain: When `NIntegrate` examines your integrand **symbolically**, it needs the power of the *Mathematica* kernel. The final integration is only a numerical scheme which can be implemented, but for this very first step, you would need to re-implement the Mathematica Kernel. As *Mathematica* is closed-source, you will have to break the law to look at its implementation. This is why I wrote it is "impossible" because many parts of *Mathematica* are black boxes that cannot be examined.

Comment: @Progo For the final numerical integration, you have much more information: You know what algorithms are used; you know what parameters are used; you can even inspect the running integration with `EvaluationMonitor`. This is why it is easier than re-implementing the Math Kernel. But to be exact: It is not *impossible* to do this. It's only far to much work to even think about it.

Comment: Ahh... Well then you have answered my question well. To find a solution from here on, I will use [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/is-there-an-open-source-implementation-of-mathematica-the-language) for a starting spot. Matlab also has an integral function which I will look very closely at. Thanks your the help!